# What does SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments() return in Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, storekit

I'm currently setting up In App Purchases for a customer for my first time, so I'm quite new to the field. I followed some tutorials to setup Auto-Renewal subscriptions and try to figure out if they should be accessible or not. I know that IAPs are not supported in simulators, but a friend mentioned that it should be possible to fetch them. Now I'm not sure and tried to use the `canMakePayments()` method to check if a connection is possible. Should it return `true` or `false` in the simulator as regular behavior? And what are the cases `canMakePayments()` returns `false` on physical devices? I did not find any helpful resources, Apple is also quite vague about it. Btw I'm using the react-native-iap package to realize the purchases, but the documentation says it's only calling the native `canMakePayments()` method. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it on the simulator? What value did you get?  You should get `false`. You will get `false` on a physical device where IAP is disabled by parental controls, where it is restricted by a management policy or where there is no active App Store account.

Comment: Yeah, I received a false but wanted to double check. But it also returns false on my iPhone. I'm running out of ideas why it doesn't work

Comment: I always receive true for canMakePayments() in both the simulator and the physical device. I tried disabling IAP in the device too. Still it return true. Any idea?